# How to property retrieve classic asp form input value

Tags: html, forms, input, vbscript, request

I have a a classic asp form on page X.asp:

```
<form method="POST" name="formname">
<input type="Hidden" name="inputname" value="1" />
</form>
```

And I am trying to retrieve the input "value" with the following code from page Y.asp:

```
Request.Form.Item("inputname")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I bet it is easy, basic syntax error, but I tried is in a bunch of different ways and cannot get it to work.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used this, but try calling without Item.

```
Request.Form("inputname")
```